# How to prevent my node+express page from being indexed by search engine?

Tags: node.js, express

I've built a site using node and express, but I would like it only to be found by people that know the address. If someone accidentally stumbles on it, it's not a big deal but I do not want it to be found through a search engine. The site is mainly under constant development and is mainly a tool for myself that is online with a public IP for the sake of convenience.

Currently I have an Express server configured with Nginx as a reverse proxy.
What is the best way to prevent the site from being indexed by search engines like google?

Comment: At a very basic level, look up how robots.txt works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about SEO which is off topic here. Delete this and instead ask on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rob I think you're making assumptions on intent. I do not care about SEO, I am trying to configure a web server to behave in a particular way.